# Different headers: Section break not working

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I've separated all sections in my document using "Section breaks".

So I have:

```
Chapter 1
=====section break======
Chapter 2
```

- First, I set the header for chapter 1.
- Then, I go to chapter 2, uncheck **link to previous** and try to change the header again. It then obstinately changes the header for the first section to "chapter 2".

Here's a sample document:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2nxnfdhxk3e0so/Section%20breaks.docx

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer finally, this had me stumped for a while. Some of word's built in headers add "Content control" such as "document title" to the header. When I type in the box, I was changing the global title of the whole document. After clicking, "Remove content control" in the box in each header, it turns out to be fine.